# Orchard: write widget which uses Images and ImagePicker

Tags: orchardcms

Are there any samples for writing a widget, which uses the imagePicker in the Dashboard?
I read through the samples, but found no hint for using pictures.

On the Dashboard I want a field called BackgroundImage, which can be picked using ImagePicker, and which must be showing as IMAGE not as path/file.
Also I want ImagePicker because it can select existing ones from Media.

Baseline: need to show a "Teaser" which consists of a BackgroundImage, Headline and Text.
These Teasers shoudl be creatable in Dashboard.
When creating a new one, I need to select existing image (or upload new one), create Headline and Text.

As a blueprint, I use the "Writing a widget" "Maps" and "Twitter" samples, I found.
But none makes use of Images.

Please give me a hint...:-)

Reinhard

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to this question [Orchard CMS Module development workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819970/orchard-cms-module-development-workflow)

It contains an example of how to add a media picker to a project custom type in a migration,
I've added some extension methods to make the migration slightly less verbose.

Hope it helps

Comment: mmmhhh... not quite.. I created a db-table with an image-path as string. now I'd like to "browse" for that file using img-picker..
 any more samples, someone?